# ) Show that if the acceleration of an object is always perpendicular to the velocity, then the speed is of the object is constant.

Tags: calculus

Since acceleration is the derivative of velocity, it should be tangent to it. How do I show this mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

$$0=\vec{a}.\vec{v}=\vec{\dot{v}}.\vec{v}=\frac12(|\vec{v}|^2)'$$
then $|\vec{v}|=C$.